# Declaring values to variables in a class(In a Top to bottom order) with an existing elements in an array

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to declare value into the variables within this class with an array of value which i currently have.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PDIPROTOTYPE2
{
    public static partial class Savestate
    {
        public static string one_one_one_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_one_two_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_one_three_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_one_four_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_one_five_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_one_six_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_one_seven_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_one_eight_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_one_nine_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_one_ten_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_one_eleven_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_one_twelve_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_one_thirteen_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_one_fourteen_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_one_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_two_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_three_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_four_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_five_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_six_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_seven_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_eight_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_nine_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_ten_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_eleven_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_twelve_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_thirteen_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_fourteen_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_fifteen_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_sixteen_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_seventeen_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_eighteen_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_nineteen_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_twenty_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_twentyone_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_twentytwo_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_twentythree_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_two_twentyfour_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_three_one_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_three_two_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_three_three_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_three_four_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_four_one_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_four_two_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_four_three_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_four_four_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_four_five_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_four_six_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_four_seven_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_four_eight_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_four_nine_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_four_ten_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_four_eleven_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_four_twelve_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_four_thirteen_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_four_fourteen_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_four_fifteen_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_four_sixteen_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_four_seventeen_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_four_eighteen_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_four_nineteen_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_four_twenty_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_four_twentyone_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_five_one_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_five_two_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_five_three_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_five_four_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_five_five_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_five_six_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_five_seven_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_five_eight_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_five_nine_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_six_one_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_six_two_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_six_three_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_six_four_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_one_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_two_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_three_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_four_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_five_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_six_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_seven_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_eight_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_nine_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_ten_one_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_ten_two_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_ten_three_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_ten_four_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_ten_five_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_ten_six_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_ten_seven_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_ten_eight_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_eleven_one_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_eleven_two_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_eleven_three_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_eleven_four_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_eleven_five_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_eleven_six_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_eleven_seven_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_seven_eleven_eight_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_eight_one_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_eight_two_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_eight_three_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_eight_four_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_eight_five_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_eight_six_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_eight_seven_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_eight_eight_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_eight_nine_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_eight_ten_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_eight_eleven_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_eight_twelve_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_nine_one_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_nine_two_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_nine_three_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_nine_four_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_nine_five_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_nine_six_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_nine_seven_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_ten_one_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_eleven_one_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_eleven_two_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_twelve_one_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_twelve_two_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_twelve_three_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_twelve_four_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_thirteen_one_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string one_thirteen_two_grouping = string.Empty;

        public static string PFS_one_one_one_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string PFS_one_one_two_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string PFS_one_one_three_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string PFS_one_one_four_grouping = string.Empty;
        public static string PFS_one_one_five_grouping = string.Empty;

        public static string edit_one_one_one_grouping = string.Empty;


        // Basic Info Variables //
        public static string Bus_Number = string.Empty;
        public static string Chassis_Number = string.Empty;
        public static string Production_Number = string.Empty;
        public static string IU_Number = string.Empty;
        public static string Model_Number = string.Empty;
        public static string Enginer_Number = string.Empty;
        public static string Transmission_Number = string.Empty;

    }
}
```

So what I aim to do is to do a loop that allows values from the array(string[] Split_CsvData ) into the individual variables within the class "Savestate". Can I have some hint on how I can make this possible?

```
string[] Split_CsvData = LoadFromSaveState.CsvData.Split('|');

for (int z = 0; z < Split_CsvData.Length; z++)
{      
    if(z == 0)
    Savestate.one_one_one_grouping = Split_CsvData[z].ToString();
}
```

Comment: First of all, you cannot modify a field that's marked with `static`. Please consider using a property instead.

Comment: @jom can i check what you mean is I cannot assign a value to a static type string variable?